# Is there any way to merge a background tune with a voice in terms of mp3 in php

Tags: php

Hi i am designating a snippet for merging a recorded voice with a background music file, is there any way to do this in php. I have searched the internet and i only found ways to concatenate two files, i want to merge them in a way that it looks like a song. Is there any way?

Comment: You need a cli tool which you can execute with `exec()`.

Comment: Actually the idea is to deploy this library on a server and automate this process

Comment: Even if you do that, you still need an external tool to process the audio files.

Comment: Processing for what, i mean what sort of processing wold that tool do

Comment: Like merging your files.

Comment: Yes do what sort of tool would do the trick for me also, would it be deployable on a server. Is there any other language that provides the tools to merge mp3 files.

Comment: I'll check this out, hope this works out.

Comment: This was helpful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697512/merging-multiple-mp3-files-overlayered-not-sequential-in-a-single-mp3-file-in?rq=1